# Is possible to avoid the 60 seconds limit in urllib2.urlopen with GAE?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, urllib2

I'm requesting a file with a size around 14MB from a slow server with urllib2.urlopen, and it spend more than 60 seconds to get the data, and I'm getting the error:

> Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL:
>   http://bigfile.zip?type=CSV

Here my code:

```
class CronChargeBT(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        taskqueue.add(queue_name = 'optimized-queue', url='/cronChargeBTB')

class CronChargeBTB(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        url = "http://bigfile.zip?type=CSV"

        url_request = urllib2.Request(url)
        url_request.add_header('Accept-encoding', 'gzip')

        urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(300)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url_request, timeout=300)

        buf = StringIO(response.read())
        f = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buf)
        ...work with the data insiste the file...
```

I create a cron task who calls CronChargeBT. Here the cron.yaml:

```
- description: cargar BlueTomato
  url: /cronChargeBT
  target: charge
  schedule: every wed,sun 01:00
```

and it create a new task and insert into a queue, here the queue configuration:

```
- name: optimized-queue
  rate: 40/s
  bucket_size: 60
  max_concurrent_requests: 10
  retry_parameters:
    task_retry_limit: 1
    min_backoff_seconds: 10
    max_backoff_seconds: 200
```

Of coursethat the timeout=300 isn't working because the 60seconds limit in GAE but I think yhat I can avoid it using a task... anyone knows how I can get the data in the file avoiding this timeout.

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Cron jobs are limited to 10 minutes deadline, not 60 seconds. If your download fails, perhaps just retry? Does the download work if you download it from your computer? There's nothing you can do on GAE if the server you are downloading from is too slow or unstable.

Edit: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests#request_timeouts, there is a maximum deadline of 60 seconds for cron job requests. Therefore, you can't get around it.

Comment: Thanks @kanghj, I think that the timeout error i'm getting is related to the urllib2.request, not the cron job. I can dowload the file from my computer, in less than 10 minutes, maybe 3 minutes, and the code is working fine in my development machine

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests#request_timeouts, there is a maximum deadline of 60 seconds for cron job requests. That could be your bottleneck here. Is that what you are observing?

Comment: Effectively you can't get around it, since its a limit imposed by GAE itself.